# Unable to utilize page objects inside before hook with webdriverIO

Tags: automated-tests, webdriver-io

Page object:

```
class Product {
   get button() { return (".element"); }
}

module.exports = new Product();
```

Code

```
var pageObject = require('../pageObjects/product.page.js');

describe("Test", function () {

   before( function () {

      browser.url();

      pageObject.button.click();
   });
```

This returns an error when the test is ran of

```
pageObject.button.click is not a function
```

I have other page objects being utilized in the test outside of the before hook that are working fine. When I move the above object outside of the hook and into the main test, it still returns the same error. It appears to be setup the same as my other page objects, so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what i can see from you `Product` class, the getter `button()` is not returning the webElement. It is returning just a string `.element`.

Please try by updating the code as like below:

```
class Product {
   get button() { return $(".element"); }
}

module.exports = new Product();
```

Thanks, Naveen

Comment: Yes, that is what was wrong. I was missing the `$` on the return element. Thanks!